# Given $T = 75e^{-2t} $ then find $t$ as a function of $f(T)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

First off, I'm sorry if some terms are wrong because I speak Spanish and I don't know how to translate them to English properly.

I'm studying computation, and I have this problem from an integral calculus course, more specifically functions.

> Given $T = f(t) = 75e^{-2t}$, find $f^{-1} (t)$.

Can anybody help me to understand how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better to ask a single question per post and add your attempts to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, fixed my question.

Comment: +1 You're welcome..To solve the problem tale logarithm on both sides.

Comment: Thanks, seeing your comment and the responses I realized that the problem it's so easy, I always block myself figuring this kind of problems require a complex solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking natural logarithms we have $$\ln(T)=\ln(75e^{-2t})=\ln(75)+\ln(e^{-2t})=\ln(75)-2t$$

$$-2t=\ln(T)-\ln(75)$$
$$t=\frac{1}{2}(\ln(75)-\ln(T))=\frac{1}{2}\ln\big(\frac{75}{T}\big)$$

for $T>0$. Thus we have $t=f(T)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\big(\frac{75}{T}\big)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, you saved me, I would never figured the solution this easy as you.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

$T =75e^{-2t} $

$e^{2t}=\dfrac{75}{T}$

$2t=\ln\dfrac{75}{T}$

$t=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln\dfrac{75}{T}$

Or

$t=\dfrac{1}{2}(\ln{75}-\ln{T})$

Comment: Wow, many thanks, you solved it so easy. I always blocked myself figuring this kind of problems require a complex solution.